# Create a list with dictionary values contained in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that associates people to their skills:

```
d = {
    'A': {'name': 'Peter', 'skill': 'python'},
    'B': {'name': 'Mary', 'skill': 'c#'},
    'C': {'name': 'James', 'skill': 'java'}
 }
```

I have a list that specified required skills for different assignments:

```
e = [
    ['python', 'java'],
    ['c#', 'R']
]
```

I need to generate a new list with name of people that have the skill requested (or 'N/A' if none found). In this case, the result will be:

```
rslt= [['Peter', 'James'], ['Mary', 'N/A']]
```

The following for-loop(s) generate the result.

```
# with for loops
for r in range(len(e)):
    for s in range(0,len(e[r])):
        skill_found = 'false'
        for k in d.keys():
            if e[r][s] == d[k]['skill']:
                rslt[r][s] = d[k]['name']
                skill_found = 'true'
                break
        if skill_found == 'false':
                rslt[r][s] = 'N/A'
print(rslt)
```

However, I'd really like to obtain some list/dictionary comprehension to do the same, which I've consistently failed at. The following two statements generate garbage:

```
#with list/dict comprehension
lstComp1 = [[d[k]['name'] if str(e[y][x]) == d[k]['skill'] else 'N/A' for x in range(0, len(e[y])) for k in d.keys()] for y in range(len(e))]
lstComp2 = [[x if x in d else 'N/A' for x in range(len(e[y]))] for y in range(len(e))]
print( lstComp1)
print(lstComp2)
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can be in dictionary `d` multiple people with same skill? Do you want only chose one person at random with required skill?

Comment: In the application I'm planning, the skill attribute will be unique (or one per person). But a more general solution (e.g., different people with same skills) one selected at random as you suggest will be interesting to have as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 3.8, you could transform the `for-loop` into one-liner:

```
d = {
    'A': {'name': 'Peter', 'skill': 'python'},
    'B': {'name': 'Mary', 'skill': 'c#'},
    'C': {'name': 'James', 'skill': 'java'}
}

e = [
    ['python', 'java'],
    ['c#', 'R']
]

rslt = [[person['name'] if any((person:=v)['skill']==skill for v in d.values()) else 'N/A' for skill in task] for task in e]

print(rslt)
```

Prints:

```
[['Peter', 'James'], ['Mary', 'N/A']]
```

Answer (score 2):

@andrej's answer is good. I have written this for any `python3.x`

`_any` is just an imitation of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) but here it returns a dictionary to make things easier.

```
def _any(d,val):
    for v in d.values():
        if v['skill']==val:
            return v
    return {'name':'N/A'}
[[_any(d,v)['name'] for v in lst] for lst in e]
# [['Peter', 'James'], ['Mary', 'N/A']]
```